# How can I get my app to cannot connect to Mongo database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I know the MongoDB database is not connecting because when I enter `asdfasdfasdfasdf` I get the "connected to DB" in the console either way.

I have my actual password in the mongodb string instead of `<passord>`.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('We are at home')
})

//Connect to DB
Mongoose.connect(
    // 'mongodb+srv://myname:<password>@cluster0.9jr1t.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
    'asdfasdfasdfasdf',
    () => console.log('connected to DB')
)

app.listen(3000);
```

I hope this is enough information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect with the database with proper error handling:

Ex:

```
mongoose
.connect(connectionString)
.then(() => {
  console.log('connected to DB')
});
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

To add to this, the ideal way to start the server with `app.listen()` is only after a **successful DB connection**. Otherwise, the server may start without connecting to the DB and would probably lead to complications.

So I suggest this:

```
mongoose
.connect(connectionString)
.then(() => {
  console.log('connected to DB');
  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'mongodb+srv://myname:' + password + '@cluster0.9jr1t.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, ((err) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    else{
        console.log('db connected');
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect)

> mongoose.connect(uri, function(error) {
> // if error is truthy, the initial connection failed.
> })

The callback function is executed whether there is an error or not, the callback should accept a parameter, and test it to see if the connection was successful or not.

Also check out the section on [error handling](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#error-handling)